# Restore Note 4 on factory settings

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-4

I have a problem I hope it has solution. I broke a display on my Note4. Phone works in behind but display is not activated at all. I went to shop but the repair cost is not worth it.
I want to sell the phone to repair dealer, but I want to bring the phone to factory settings and delete ally media.
How can I do that when the display broken?
I tried to connect it to PC. Windows 10 recognizes it and I get an icon of the phone. But when I click it no content is shown

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the phone,. Once fully off hold volume down and power, it will bring you to the recovery menu, using the volume buttons navigate the menu and use power as your enter button, should have reset to factory or wipe user data as a option.  Not sure if it will need a on-screen button press but only other way is from that recovery menu you would be able to flash the partitions via adb or if you unlocked your bootloader it would auto wipe the user partition. Which doesn't need on screen confirmation.  But there are your options.